# How to create multiple DE's from an array using SSJS (via an Automation Studio Script Activity)

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, automationstudio

Is there a way to dynamically generate multiple DE's based on an array? Something that might look like below? And, something that generates a new variable name (see line 6 & 27 should be the same values)? I'm not certain how to get lines 6 - 25 to repeat based on the number of values present in the "var name" array.

```
1  | <script runat=server>
2  | var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
3  | var name = ["deRed","deGreen","deBlue"];
4  | var desc = ["descRed","descGreen","descBlue"];
5  |
6  | var [somethingDynamic] = {
7  | Name: name,
8  | CustomerKey: name,
9  | Description: desc,
10 | Fields: [{
11 |    FieldType: "Text",
12 |    Name: "SubscriberKey",
13 |    MaxLength: 254,
14 |    IsPrimaryKey: true,
15 |    IsNillable: false,
16 |    IsRequired: true
17 | },
18 | {
19 |    FieldType: "EmailAddress",
20 |    Name: "EmailAddress",
21 |    IsNillable: false,
22 |    IsRequired: true
23 | }],
24 | CategoryID: 123
25 | }
26 |
27 | var res = prox.createBatch("DataExtension", [somethingDynamic]);
28 | </script>
```

--
SFMC Documentation Reference: [Create via WSProxy](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_WSProxy_create.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a for loop and utilise [Array.prototype.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) to create your array of DE objects for the WSProxy batch call.

```
<script runat=server>
    Platform.Load("Core", "1");

    var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
    var name = ["deRed", "deGreen", "deBlue"];
    var desc = ["descRed", "descGreen", "descBlue"];
    var objs = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
        var somethingDynamic = {
            Name: name[i],
            CustomerKey: name[i],
            Description: desc[i],
            Fields: [{
                    FieldType: "Text",
                    Name: "SubscriberKey",
                    MaxLength: 254,
                    IsPrimaryKey: true,
                    IsNillable: false,
                    IsRequired: true
                },
                {
                    FieldType: "EmailAddress",
                    Name: "EmailAddress",
                    IsNillable: false,
                    IsRequired: true
                }
            ],
            CategoryID: 123
        }

        objs.push(somethingDynamic);
    }

    var res = prox.createBatch("DataExtension", objs);
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry @Josh do Blank. I think I accidentally edited your answer as it looked pretty identical to the one I was working on at the same time. My bad.

Comment: All good. thanks @Macca.

Comment: So, I put this in the script activity for Automation Studio. It validates and runs. It does not, however, place the DE's. I've double-checked the CategoryID and that was okay. Would you happen to know anything I could check? Since it's not throwing an error, I'm not sure where to start. @JoshdeBlank

Comment: I've tested the code in a Cloudpage and it works as expected. Only item I changed was the category ID to one relevant to my instance. By testing in cloudpages you can see the returned result by using `Write(Stringify(res));` after your proxy function call.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would benefit most from checking out some JS tutorials on iteration like [this one from MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration)

Also, you wouldn't want to iterate over multiple arrays that contain related properties for the DE's you are trying to create. You should be using [objects for that.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)